# Issue with Robolectric 2.2 and ActionBarSherlock 4.2.0

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, robolectric

we have around 700 tests with Robolectric 1.x and I started migration to 2.x. After long day I have around 57 tests failing and almost all with similar exception:

```
android.view.InflateException: XML file ./res/layout/view.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class <unknown>
....
java.lang.RuntimeException: huh? ResName{android:style/TextAppearance_Sherlock_Light_Small}
```

I wonder if someone knows how to fix this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robolectric 2.x had an issue that custom attribute is mixed up with android internal attribute. In this case, ActionBarSherlock's TextAppearance_Sherlock_Light_Small attribute is mixed up with Android's one.

[This pull request](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/pull/685) should solve the issue, so please try the latest Robolectric from GitHub. (I myself confirmed that that error is fixed on the latest)